# When gitlab says make a file executable what exactly do they mean?

Tags: permissions, hook, gitlab

Gitlab says "[Make the hook file executable and make sure it's owned by git](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/custom_hooks.html)" , but I read [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm) that a file can be executable by owner, group, world. So which one do they mean?

Right now I am changing

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 git  git     0 Jun 24 00:32 pre-receive
```

to

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 git  git     0 Jun 24 00:32 pre-receive
```

Is this sufficient to just make it executable for the owner?

Comment: That surprisingly looks good at first glance.  Did you try it?  After looking at it again though, it seems to be missing content (its size is 0 bytes).

Comment: yup it works :)

Comment: but my question was more like -- in general when people say to make a file "executable" do they mean to make it executable by the owner or by owner, group, and public?

Comment: Since they mentioned the owner to set, I suppose they intended the file to be run by that user.  There is no general absolute rule on how tutorials should phrase their instructions.

Answer (score 1):

They mean "make it executable by the user that will be invoking the application". This is usually what is meant by "making a file executable" when nothing else is specified.

If only the `git` user should be able to execute the file, make it executable by the owner only.  This may be what they mean since it's a server-side hook.  If *anyone* should be able to execute the file, the file needs to be executable by everyone (this is less likely the intention).

Hence (possibly with `sudo`):

```
$ chown git pre-receive
$ chmod u+x pre-receive     # or a+x if anyone should be able to run it
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed what I proposed above worked. The answer is to do

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 git  git     0 Jun 24 00:32 pre-receive
```